# Retrieve data from Dynamodb using composite primary key in android

Tags: android

I have table Customers on **dynamodb** where my hash key is a  **phonenumber(number)** and my sort key is date(string).

I have tried following solution

```
Customers customer= mapper.load(Customers .class, "123456789");
```

(where, 123456789 is my hash key)

but unable to get data.Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Method provided here:

`Customers customer= mapper.load(Customers .class, "123456789","Your Range Key");`

Where one of the Key in the Argument is a Primary Key(Hash Key) and another one is Range Key, that you defined in the table.

Note:

You have to use annotation @DynamoDBHashKey for one of the Primary Keys in the class definition in your application code, so that above query works.

Read about DynamoDBRangeKey here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html